# JSON Array is apparently null, but it shouldn't be

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

Edit: I was parsing the wrong file! I was getting errors because I was treating the file as an array, but it was the wrong file

---

I need to parse a JSON file that is just one whole array. I want to access "text" within the "data" array.

JSON File:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12243",
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "testing",
        "userDefined": false
      }
    ],
    "countCheck": false,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

Java Code:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(files[i])));
org.json.simple.JSONArray data = (org.json.simple.JSONArray)object.get("data");
```

This compiles and runs BUT "data" is apparently null, and I have no idea why. Also, object is NOT null.

Comment: Are you sure that exact data is going into your parser?

Comment: Based on your json file, are you sure `object` isn't an array? You should be getting an exception when casting to JSONObject

Comment: It runs? Without throwing exception? Because the JSON starts with a `[`, so the root is an array, and casting to `JSONObject` should then throw a class cast exception.

Comment: your first line suggests what you read from the file is a single JSON object when in fact it's a JSON array

Comment: The top level of the JSON is an array, not an object, so casting the output of `parse()` to `JSONObject` is wrong. Try casting it to `JSONArray` instead, and then access the `JSONObject` at index 0, and then get the `"data"` field of that object.

Comment: That's the odd thing! I was also trying to treat it as a JSON Array, but when I deal with it as such, I get the error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Comment: What do you get when you output `object.toString()`? That _should_ clarify a lot...

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Ok so it seems like it doesn't matter whether I cast ouput of parse() to an object OR an array, both work until I try to do something with them. Such as object.toString() or array.size(). So casting doesn't give me a problem until I do something with the ouput

Comment: So eliminate the cast altogether. `Object object = parser.parse(...);`. What does `object.toString()` or `object.getClass().getName()` then return?

Comment: object.getClass().getName() gives me org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: and `object.toString()`?

Comment: @banzba: If `parse()` is returning a `JSONObject` instead of a `JSONArray`, then you have bigger problems to deal with, since the JSON you showed clearly begins with an array and not an object. Try a different JSON parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level of the JSON is an array, not an object, so casting the output of `parse()` to `JSONObject` is wrong. Cast it to `JSONArray` instead, and then access the `JSONObject` at index 0, and then get the `"data"` field of that object:

```
JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(files[i])));
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) arr.get(0);
JSONArray data = (JSONArray) object.get("data");
```

And then you can iterate the objects in the `data` array as needed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
    String text = obj.get("text");
    //...
}
```

```
for (JSONObject obj : data)
{
    String text = obj.get("text");
    //...
}
```

Etc...

Comment: I did exactly that and I end up getting the error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
"

Comment: @banzba -- so what ended up being the problem? How did you get past your `ClassCastException` issue?